# Issue of connecting ubuntu to github

Tags: ubuntu, github

I have been facing the issue of pushing to github , everytime i push it is asking for my username and password thus wasting a lot of time. Is there a way to premanently connect github account to my ubuntu linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be to set up an SSH connection with GitHub. You can follow the walkthrough under "Connect With SSH" here https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh